# ErrorException in {} Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, web

I am facing a problem that undefined offset :1 in line 3. I can't understand that what type of error it is. Can anyone tell me that why such error occurs in laravel

my Controller :

```js
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $kode_tempat_ujian = $request-> input ('kode_tempat_ujian');
    $kode_jenis_ujian = $request-> input ('kode_jenis_ujian');
    $kode_jenis_d20an = $request-> input ('kode_jenis_d20an');
    $hari = $request-> input ('hari');
    $ruang = $request-> input ('ruang');
    $kode_lokasi_ujian = $request-> input ('kode_lokasi_ujian');


        $data = new AlokasiRuang;
        $simpan = $data->IsiAlokasiRuang($kode_tempat_ujian, $kode_jenis_ujian, $kode_jenis_d20an, $hari, $ruang, $kode_lokasi_ujian);
        if($simpan){
          Session::flash('message', [ 'message' => 'Data Berhasil Ditambahkan',
                    'action'=>'success' ] );
          return redirect('master/alokasiruang');
        }else{
          Session::flash('message', [ 'message' => 'Data Gagal Ditambakan Karena Primary Key Sudah Digunakan',
                    'action'=>'error' ] );
          return redirect('master/alokasiruang');
        }
    }
```

```js
public static function IsiAlokasiRuang ($kode_tempat_ujian, $kode_jenis_ujian, $kode_jenis_d20an, $hari, $ruang, $kode_lokasi_ujian)
    {
      try {
        $isi = DB::insert( DB::raw("INSERT into t_alokasi_ruang_ujian (kode_tempat_ujian, kode_jenis_ujian, kode_jenis_d20an, hari, ruang, kode_lokasi_ujian)
    values (:kode_tempat_ujian, :kode_jenis_ujian, :kode_jenis_d20an, :hari, :ruang, :kode_lokasi_ujian)"),
        array( 'kode_tempat_ujian' => $kode_tempat_ujian, 'kode_jenis_ujian' => $kode_jenis_ujian, 'hari' => $hari, 'ruang' => $ruang, 'kode_lokasi_ujian' => $kode_lokasi_ujian
          ));

   return $isi;

      }catch (QueryException $e) {
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1]; //<== this is line 83
        if($errorCode == 1062){
            return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

The eror log:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ErrorException in AlokasiRuang.php line 83: Undefined offset: 1

    in AlokasiRuang.php line 83
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 1', 'D:\lokalapp\srs4g1\app\Models\Master\AlokasiRuang.php', '83', array('kode_tempat_ujian' => '101', 'kode_jenis_ujian' => '3', 'kode_jenis_d20an' => '4', 'hari' => '2', 'ruang' => '555', 'kode_lokasi_ujian' => '10B', 'e' => object(QueryException))) in AlokasiRuang.php line 83
    at AlokasiRuang::IsiAlokasiRuang('101', '3', '4', '2', '555', '10B') in AlokasiRuangController.php line 110
    at AlokasiRuangController->store(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AlokasiRuangController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
    at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AlokasiRuangController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AlokasiRuangController), object(Route), object(Request), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Master\AlokasiRuangController', 'store') in Route.php line 174
    at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
```

So thank you before, i know its dumb, i just started using laravel. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error in on **line 83** Where is line **83**

Comment: }catch (QueryException $e) {
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
        if($errorCode == 1062){
            return false;
      }

Comment: remove the `[1]` from `}catch (QueryException $e) { $errorCode = $e->errorInfo; if($errorCode == 1062){ return false; } `

Comment: You will then get another error about what is wrong with your query

Comment: Why are you calling a static function through a class instance? Is there any reason you've made it static?

Comment: Which is of course is that you have 6 columns parameters and only 5 data values

Comment: Do a var_dump of ` $e->errorInfo` and check if it's an array.

Try to use specific exceptions classes like [mysqli_sql_exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php)

Comment: i got it, you solved it @RiggsFolly